# How can I get access token from instagram login api without using redirect uri?

Tags: react-native, instagram-api

I'm working with Instagram api in my react native app for login purpose. I have used redirect URI in my api as stated in docs but the problem is after logging in with the Instagram from let's say screen A, I am being redirected to some another screen of my app (let's say screen B) but when I press back button from that screen B, I'm being sent back to the redirect URI and then screen A.

So is there any way to prevent the redirection to the URI and send the user back to directly screen A when clicking back button on screen B.

Thanks in advance.